# How can I count the number of items in a parameter that is a range?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to write a custom function that need to do math with the first and last items in a range. I know the first is just `ParameterName(1)` but I know I need to count them for the last item. How would I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
ParameterName.Cells(ParameterName.Cells.Count)
```

...assuming a single-area range